# Multiple chat rooms, technologies and server load,

Tags: php, load, chat

I am working on a website where I need multiple chat rooms. Each room will be generated and tied to the content/event just generated by the user and will aproximately last 15 minutes and then autodestroyed. One room will contain aprox. 15 users. Many events will co-exist at the same time.

I have been googling around a lot recently looking for the most appropriate but still easily implementable solution. What I came across are three main paths:

1. using a mysql-php ready made script (ie. phpfreechat, x7 chat)
2. using irc channels created on the fly through an ajax or flash web frontend embeded as an iframe (lightirc, qwebirc, mibbit, (advice more if u want))
3. using some lively generated hosted chatrooms (ie. everywherechat.com, gabbly (i really need to know more of those, again, advice if you can).

Still I have many doubts on all this: irc frontends cant be customized as much as I'd need (ie. disable kick or ban functionalities). Php-mysql solutions, on the other hand, make me think there will be a lot of server load concerns with such a big user-base.

I am on a paid but non dedicated hosting plan. Php memory limit set to 64mb kind of stuff. How many users at the same time would that hold? Hosted solutions are the easiest ones, but can you recommend one that allows rooms to be created on the fly by just passing in some parameters? (no registration, just a quick-easy-flying chatroom).

I know many of these questions are not strictly programming related but more technology related. But still a programming related answer could help me sort out the right direction. So your contribution is really appreciated. Thanks ! Sorry for being long

Comment: A paid-but-non-dedicated hosting plan likely won't let you run an IRC server at all.

Comment: by irc i meant using some free existing irc servers on big irc networks

Comment: i really think you should CSS you question mate, can't even look at it :S

Comment: @jjj That has similar issues - are the major IRC networks going to look kindly on you using their bandwidth and systems for your application?

Comment: @ceejayoz suppose it would be aprox 1000 users at the same maximum, and maybe that i could split them across 10 different servers on the same irc network... I don't really think that would be a problem. But as i've written on Q, could i customize an irc web client to disable certain irc features?

Comment: @jjj + @anyone_who_answers , Question : Will the server load be significant using limit on SQL query and using some automated script to remove old messages once an hour?

Comment: @jjj: remember, it might be only 1000 users on your site, but it'd still be 1000 connections from your vps to the IRC network. Server ops would view it as a spam operation, most likely, since no legitimate SINGLE user would ever have more than 1 or 2 connections at any time. Boom goes your connection with a +k

Comment: @Marc B no way, each user would be on their own ip's. It's a direct connection through users and irc

Comment: And how are you going to get the client browsers to connect to the IRC server?

Comment: @MarcB http://wiki.mibbit.com/index.php/WebIRC